# Twilio incoming call issue in twilio iOS Sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twilio

I am using twilio iOS sdk in my application and am having problem with incoming call . I can able to get incoming call, but the caller disconnect the call after he spoke i didn't get any  callback in my app. so i can't able to identify that call has been disconnected in my app.

Note: 
Right  now I'm using the below callback method in my application, it has been called once when the incoming call is ignore, but it didn't call when the caller spoke and disconnect the call.

```
- (void)connectionDidDisconnect:(TCConnection *)connection
```

Answer (score -1):

You might try to update your code with a call to `- (void)disconnectAll` after a caller disconnects.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/tcdevice#disconnectAll

This a convenience routine that disconnects all current incoming and outgoing connections.

Comment: Caller will call from phone or a Skype then how do we know caller disconnects the call ?

Comment: The link is not valid